# Creating view with missing data records for key values

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

We have a table with some set of rows.
We want to create a view with missing rows for key columns and fill the other non key values using the last available values.

Key columns - Name, year & period.
We have to populate salary based on previously available key set, if it was missing.

**Current data in table :**

[image]

**Expected data set :**

[image]

Here, the rows highlighted in green are appended based and values populated using last available key set.

**Request :**

Any idea how can I create the view
I tried but i am not seeing the data as expected.

**This is what I tried**

```
WITH “EMP”
AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE
  FROM EMP_TBL
  )
  ,"QTR"
AS (
  SELECT 'Q1' QUARTER
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT 'Q2' QUARTER
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT 'Q3' QUARTER
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT 'Q4' QUARTER
  )
  ,"YR"
AS (
  SELECT '2015' "YEAR"
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT '2016' "YEAR"
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT '2017' "YEAR"
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT '2018' "YEAR"
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT '2019' "YEAR"
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT '2020' "YEAR"
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT '2021' "YEAR"
  )
  ,”EMP_Y_QTR"
AS (
  SELECT EMPLOYEE
    ,YEAR
    ,QUARTER
  FROM “EMP”
  CROSS JOIN "QTR"
  CROSS JOIN "YR"
  )
  ,"CURR_DATA"
AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE
    ,YEAR
    ,QTR
    ,'Y' FLAG
  FROM EMP_FACT_TABLE
  )
  ,"REF_DATA"
AS (
  SELECT A.EMPLOYEE
    ,A.YEAR
    ,A.QUARTER
    ,B.YEAR AS YEAR_TO_BE_APPLIED
    ,B.QTR AS QTR_TO_BE_APPLIED
    ,B.FLAG
  FROM EMP_Y_QTR A
  LEFT JOIN "CURR_DATA" B ON A.EMPLOYEE = B.EMPLOYEE
    AND A.YEAR = B.YEAR
    AND A.QUARTER = B.QTR
  )
  ,REF_DATA_PROC
AS (
  SELECT *
    ,COALESCE(YEAR_TO_BE_APPLIED, (
        LAG(YEAR_TO_BE_APPLIED) OVER (
          ORDER BY EMPLOYEE
            ,YEAR
            ,QUARTER
          )
        ), (
        LEAD(YEAR_TO_BE_APPLIED) OVER (
          ORDER BY EMPLOYEE
            ,YEAR
            ,QUARTER
          )
        )) AS YEAR_APPLY
    ,COALESCE(QTR_TO_BE_APPLIED, (
        LAG(QTR_TO_BE_APPLIED) OVER (
          ORDER BY EMPLOYEE
            ,YEAR
            ,QUARTER
          )
        ), (
        LEAD(QTR_TO_BE_APPLIED) OVER (
          ORDER BY EMPLOYEE
            ,YEAR
            ,QUARTER
          )
        )) AS QUARTER_APPLY
  FROM REF_DATA T
  )
  ,EMP_FACT_TABLE_DATA
AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE]
    ,[CITY]
    ,[YEAR]
    ,[QTR]
    ,[ADDRESS]
    ,[SALARY]
      FROM [EMP_FACT_TABLE]
  )
SELECT [EMPLOYEE]
    ,[CITY]
    ,[YEAR]
    ,[QTR]
    ,[ADDRESS]
    ,[SALARY]
FROM REF_DATA_PROC B
LEFT JOIN EMP_FACT_TABLE_DATA A ON A.EMPLOYEE = B.EMPLOYEE
  AND B.YEAR = A.YEAR
  AND B.QUARTER = A.QTR
WHERE A.EMPLOYEE = B.EMPLOYEE
  AND B.YEAR_APPLY = A.YEAR
  AND B.QUARTER_APPLY = A.QTR
```

Comment: Your tables don't reflect what you said, some rows have changed.

Comment: I have updated the data sets, can u please check now.

Comment: Images of data don't help us help you; take the time to post it as DDL and DML statements. Also, what have *you* tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: What you need is a calendar dimension table.

Comment: hello @Larnu, I have added the query i tried. can u please help fix the query I am not seeing the data populated for missing years so the request

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by evaluating a distinct list of Names and periods, cross join it and then left join your initial table - however, depending on the amount of data, this will require quite some time, since cross joins usually aren't the tool of choice... anyways, here an example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(cName varchar(10), cYear int, cPeriod char(2), cSalary int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Mark', 2019, 'Q1', 100)
,('Mark', 2019, 'Q2', 200)
,('Mark', 2019, 'Q4', 400)
,('Mark', 2020, 'Q1', 500)
,('Mark', 2020, 'Q3', 600)
,('Mark', 2020, 'Q4', 480)


;WITH ctePeriods AS(
SELECT DISTINCT t.cYear, p.cPeriod
  FROM @t t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Q1' AS cPeriod UNION ALL SELECT 'Q2' UNION ALL SELECT 'Q3' UNION ALL SELECT 'Q4') p
),
ctePersonPeriods AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT t.cName, p.cYear, p.cPeriod
    FROM @t t
    CROSS JOIN ctePeriods p
),
cteSalary AS(
SELECT p.cName, p.cYear, p.cPeriod, t.cSalary
  FROM ctePersonPeriods p
  LEFT JOIN @t t ON t.cName = p.cName AND t.cYear = p.cYear AND t.cPeriod = p.cPeriod
 )
 SELECT cName, cYear, cPeriod, ISNULL(cSalary, LAG(cSalary) OVER (PARTITION BY cName ORDER BY cYear, cPeriod)) AS cSalary
  FROM cteSalary
```

Comment: hello @tyron78 , will it work if 2 of the rows are missing ( lag > 1+ )